# Even columns not rendering in tikz-cd diagram in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, errors, tikz-cd, undefined

I am getting two errors when seeking to use copy this matrix over to my beamer presentation slides:

> Undefined control sequence.

> Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode. (This one occurs twice).

A reproducible version of the faulty code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usefonttheme{default}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, tikz-cd}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm}
    
$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, row sep = 8, column sep = 4]
0\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r] & 3\arrow[r] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 9 \\
5\arrow[d] & 1\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 3\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 7 \\
8\arrow[d] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 5\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 6 & 8\arrow[d] \\
15\arrow[d] & 11\arrow[d] & 7\arrow[d] & 6\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 10 \\
18 & 14 & 10 & 9 & 11 \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is not rendering the matrix properly. It is not showing the even columns:

[image: Incorrect Output]

I first successfully created the diagram in a separate project which is coded as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, row sep = 8, column sep = 4]
0\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r] & 3\arrow[r] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 9 \\
5\arrow[d] & 1\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 3\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 7 \\
8\arrow[d] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 5\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 6 & 8\arrow[d] \\
15\arrow[d] & 11\arrow[d] & 7\arrow[d] & 6\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 10 \\
18 & 14 & 10 & 9 & 11 \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

This correctly rendered the output:

[image: Correct Output]

**Why the image is not rendering properly in my presentation slides, when I have simply copied the code over? Is there a way to get the desired outcome?**

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example which shows us the actual line breaks as they are in your document?

Comment: I suspect you just need the `fragile` frame option, but with the missing line breaks and comments in the preamble it is hard to tell...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, are you asking me to post the code without editing out the line breaks?

Comment: I'd like to see the code as it is in your actual document. If the line breaks are there in your document, show them. If they are not there in your actual document, that's an error.

Comment: (as for your second document: your are missing the frame environment and thus your content won't be positioned correctly on the page. You always need a frame environment with beamer)

Comment: Putting the "good" code inside a frame command caused the same error initially described @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: See my answer below, you are missing the `fragile` frame option

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `fragile` frame option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usefonttheme{default}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, tikz-cd}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm}
    
$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, row sep = 8, column sep = 4]
0\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r] & 3\arrow[r] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 9 \\
5\arrow[d] & 1\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 2\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 3\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 7 \\
8\arrow[d] & 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 5\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] & 6 & 8\arrow[d] \\
15\arrow[d] & 11\arrow[d] & 7\arrow[d] & 6\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] & 10 \\
18 & 14 & 10 & 9 & 11 \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively you could replace all the `&` by something else, but that's certainly more tedious than using the `fragile` frame option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usefonttheme{default}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, tikz-cd}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm}
    
$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, row sep = 8, column sep = 4,ampersand replacement=\&]
0\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 2\arrow[r] \& 3\arrow[r] \& 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] \& 9 \\
5\arrow[d] \& 1\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 2\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 3\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 7 \\
8\arrow[d] \& 4\arrow[r]\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 5\arrow[r]\arrow[dr] \& 6 \& 8\arrow[d] \\
15\arrow[d] \& 11\arrow[d] \& 7\arrow[d] \& 6\arrow[dr]\arrow[d] \& 10 \\
18 \& 14 \& 10 \& 9 \& 11 \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]